# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de un código de barras con un lector de código de barras desde mi viewmodel sin necesidad de un textbox? wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, código-de-barras, viewmodel

Quiero obtener el código de barras que me devuelve un lector de código de barra sin necesidad de que el focus este en un textbox, que solo necesite estar abierta una vista.

Por ahora lo que estoy haciendo es esto en mi Vista

```
<UserControl x:Class="Capa_Presentacion_WPF.Views.AutoServicio.AutoServicio"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Capa_Presentacion_WPF.Views.AutoServicio"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local11="clr-namespace:Capa_Entidades.Models;assembly=Capa_Entidades"
             mc:Ignorable="d"            
             d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1130" Background="Lavender"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             KeyDown="UserControl_KeyDown">
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=EnterCommand}" Key="Enter"/>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF1Command}" Key="F1" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF2Command}" Key="F2" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF3Command}" Key="F3" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF4Command}" Key="F4" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=KeyF12Command}" Key="F12" />
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
</UserControl>
```

El primer **<KeyBinding** me referencia cuando detecta el "enter", ya que los códigos que se leen con el lector vienen con un enter al ultimo. Estaba pensando en usar eso, pero el problema ahí es ¿Como obtengo el código anterior al "enter"?

Lo otro que ya esta es que programo en un textbox, pero eso es lo que no quiero, simplemente quiero obtener el código y que ejecute una función al leer el código de barras, sin necesidad de estar en un textbox o en cualquier otro control.

Comment: Hola, Jimel. ¿Has intentado algo para obtener lo que necesitas? Podrías mostrarnos parte del código y el error que te da y de esa forma podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar mi pregunta para explicar mejor lo que quiero hacer, espero que me puedas ayudar @AdrianFusco

Answer (score 0):

Sin un TextBox? Podrías tratar esto, ojo que no uso los mismos nombres de tu codigo:

Las Window tienen un evento llamado TextInput, que se lanza al detectar el ingreso de texto, las pistolas lectoras hacen justamente eso.

Lo que deberías hacer es, suponiendo que creas la instancia del ViewModel en el XAML de tu ventana de este modo:

```
<UserControl 
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Capa_Presentacion_WPF.ViewModels"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:MyViewModel  x:Key="MyVM"/>
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyVM}">
    
</Gri>
</UserControl>
```

Crear un llamado a ese ViewModel en el codebehind y usar el evento TextInput para conectar el texto que recibes de la pistola con tu string en el viewModel

```
private MyViewModel _myVModel;

public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _myVModel = (MyViewModel)FindResource("MyVM"); //name in xaml
}

private void OnTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    _myVModel.MyString = e.Text;
}
```

Y eso debería funcionar, solo necesitarías validar que el ingreso se hará con el focus en la ventana sino se lanzará cada vez que pulses una tecla con esa ventana abierta.